# BigQuery: How to query firebase daily events table dynamically?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I want to schedule a query which takes data from Firebase daily events table (the day before) and update another table. (I got it working with manually specifying the source full table name)

I thought the events table is just a partitioned table but it doesn't look like it.
Here is what it looks like on UI:

[image]
As you can see there are actually 16 tables under `events_` which are actually daily tables.
How can I dynamically specify the name of the table I want to query?

Here is what I tried but it's obviously not working: (numbers altered)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `appname-11111.analytics_11111111.events_`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Comment: Does it work with `_TABLE_SUFFIX` instead of `_PARTITIONTIME`? Note that you need to have a `*` after the `events_`, e.g. `events_*` to match multiple tables.

Comment: Almost, here is the two relevant parts: `FROM 'appname-e1111.analytics_111111.events_*'
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))`

Comment: So... Does that query work, then? It's not clear what you're stuck on.

Comment: It works, feel free to post it as an answer :)

Comment: Great! I posted an answer with a link to the wildcard table documentation, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want this instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `appname-11111.analytics_11111111.events_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

See the [wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) documentation for more reading. The short summary is that the events "table" is really a collection of tables with a common prefix (different from a partitioned table, which is a single table with multiple dates), and the * syntax lets you refer to more than one table at once.